# CSS files collided in Laravel and Vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm using Laravel, Vue, Inertia, and tailwind css as a template for the auth pages.

The code is like this (app.css)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The problem is, I have another multiple css files that I have imported to app.js like this

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';
import '../css/navbar.css';
import '../css/home.css';
import '../css/kenapa.css';
import '../css/ceritakami.css';
import '../css/karir.css';
import '../css/lowongan.css';
import '../css/media.css';
import '../css/gabung.css';
import '../css/mitra.css';
import '../css/download.css';
import '../css/footer.css';
import '../css/login.css';
```

And so, the tailwind file is messing up my .Vue files.

What should I do to separate them without colliding with each other in app.js ? I'm hoping to achieve that the front end pages is using the CSS files I've created myself, and the auth pages is using the tailwind ones.

Comment: I suggest that you either use interita.js or vue.js and either bootstrap or tailwind. 
You can create the auth pages in a bootstrap with following command, but this will override your existing views: `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth`
Another approach would be including different scripts and sytlesheets depending on the site. You could create a TailwindLayout and a BootstrapLayout which your blade files can extend...

Comment: you can remove `import '../css/app.css';` from global and add it only in *selected vue components* inside style tag .. `<style>@import './assets/styles/css/app.css';</style>`